# Is this a fossil or a mark on the stone

Tags: fossils

[image]Found this rock during a walk along the coast and I can't tell weather the white line is a fossil or just a mark on the rock. Any help in identifing weather this is a fossil or not would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read [this guide](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/124/6) and add as much information as you can.

Comment: It could be a body fossil or a trace fossil (also called an ichnofossil). A clearer image could help as well as a good rock description. Cheers!